# Loading an iframe on click of a trigger using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

I am working on a search engine based site that uses iframes to embed google maps onto each search engine result. The problem is most users don't care about seeing a map, and loading 20 iframes on every search result page when the chance of more than 1 of them being viewed are pretty slim, is bad because slows down the load time of the site. I am trying to load the iframe that is inside a container with the class "address-popup" only on click of a trigger with the "address-link". I set the display of the iframe to none in my css, though it still seems to load, even before it is visible.

trigger code:

```
<span class="address-link">Address</span>
```

iframe code:

```
echo '<div class="address-popup">
            <iframe class="map" style="margin-top:45px;" width="570" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q='.$addressString.'&amp;aq=&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear='.$addressString.'&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>
       </div>';
```

Comment: I think you are missing the js code

Answer (score 1):

You can have all the iframe's code in the javascript. If you like using jQuery, this would do it:

```
$('.address-link').click(function(){
   $('.address-popup').html('<iframe class="map" style="margin-top:45px;" width="570" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q='.$addressString.'&amp;aq=&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear='.$addressString.'&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>'); 
});
```

One way of being more specific might be to define the id of the target container with a data attribute, like so:

HTML

```
<span class="address-link" data-target-id="target-div-7">Address</span>
<div id="target-div-7"></div> <!-- target div -->
```

jQuery

```
$('.address-link').click(function(){
   var targetId = $(this).data('target-id');
   $('#' + targetId).html('<iframe class="map" style="margin-top:45px;" width="570" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" src="https://maps.google.com/maps?f=q&amp;source=s_q&amp;hl=en&amp;geocode=&amp;q='.$addressString.'&amp;aq=&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear='.$addressString.'&amp;t=m&amp;z=14&amp;iwloc=A&amp;output=embed"></iframe>'); 
});
```

So for every trigger, you can define the target id as a data attribute, and you can use the same script.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However, what if I have 20 of these .address-link containers and I want to load ONLY the iframe where where the trigger was clicked on?

Answer (score 1):

Why use iframes?  You can just load a Google map directly in a common "pop-up" DIV, then center that map to the selected address with each link click.  This would likely perform much better than loading entire HTML pages.

Here is a working example from a proof of concept where I helped a friend of mine implement the javascript/maps functionality.

```
http://184.106.239.214/pacific_grove_zoning/
```

Just look as the source code.  You can see the map changes by just starting to type some address ("1234..", "1000...", etc.) in the autocomplete field and then selecting an address.

Here is the main portion of javascript from this site that is relevant to the google maps functionality

```
function map_initialize() {
    // instantiate google map
    var initialLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(37.4328, -122.077);
    var initialOptions = {
        zoom: 18,
        center: initialLatlng,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID
    }
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('property_map'), initialOptions);
    geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
}

function map_to_address(address) {
    if (marker != undefined) {
        marker.setMap(null);
    }
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
      if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
        map.setCenter(results[0].geometry.location);
        // map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.bounds);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location
        });
      } else {
        alert("Unable to map provided address. Error: " + status);
      }
    });
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Can you please elaborate how to embed a Google map without an iframe?